# REST API social Login in cakephp

Tags: angularjs, cakephp

i am a newbie to Cakephp 3.*, I was playing around with cakephp REST API and angularjs. So far i was able to successfully integrate the registeration and login using the ADmad/JwtAuth ([Link](http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-add-jwt-authentication-to-a-cakephp-3-rest-api/)). I want to add social login as well (My application is a stateless, as all the back-end related queries are in the REST API)how can i do this?

Please Help.
Thanks